# Establishing simultaneity with light signals, sound waves and identical particles

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, time

On the site [mathpages.com](https://www.mathpages.com/) I encountered the following statement by Kevin Brown in his wonderful article "[Teaching Special Relativity](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath684/kmath684.htm)" (2nd paragraph):

*For example, they [students] imagine that we could just as well use sound waves (albeit in an unrealistic perfectly stationary and homogeneous medium) to establish simultaneity, but of course this is not true, since the recoverable kinetic energy of a particle does not approach infinity as the speed of the particle approaches the speed of sound. The root cause of the student’s misunderstanding is that most presentations of the subject follow Einstein’s 1905 paper in neglecting to clearly identify the operational definition of simultaneity that forms the basis of Newtonian physics...*

*...Newton’s third law holds good only if we define the synchronization of clocks such that two identical particles initially adjacent and at rest in the frame and exerting mutual repulsive forces on each other will travel equal distances in equal times.*

Brown seems to reject establishing simultaneity based on sound waves because *the recoverable kinetic energy of a particle does not approach infinity as the speed of the particle approaches the speed of sound*. Yet we can establish simultaneity based on Newton's third law, with identical particles traveling equal distances in equal time. How is this different than sound waves, since *the recoverable kinetic energy of a particle does not approach infinity as the speed of the particle approaches the speed of* the particles used for synchronization?

Given the quality of the article and the site in general, I suspect there is something I don't get, rather than a simple mistake in the source. Could you help me out?